# Differentiate $[x^{5\coth(6x)}]'$

Tags: derivatives, hyperbolic-functions

can you help me to differentiate this function?
$$[x^{5\coth(6x)}]'$$

My steps:

$$[x^{5\coth(6x)}*\ln(x)]*[5(1-\coth^2(6x))]*[6]$$

I dont know what formula i should use $$[x^n]'$$ or $$[a^x]'$$
thanks for advice.

Comment: You are dealing with $x^{f(x)}$ which is $\exp [f(x)\ln x]$, can differentiate the second function?

Comment: Take $\log$ then diferentiate, and then take $exp$.

Comment: Is cotgh the hyperbolic cotangent? Most people denote it by coth.

Comment: yes it is a hyperbolic cotangent

Comment: Just FYI ... there is no such word as "derivate."  The verb for taking a derivative is "to differentiate."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^{5\coth(6x)}\right)=$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{\left(5\coth(6x)\right)\ln(x)}\right)=$$
$$\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(5\coth(6x)\ln(x)\right)\right)e^{\left(5\coth(6x)\right)\ln(x)}=$$
$$x^{5\coth(6x)}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(5\coth(6x)\ln(x))=$$
$$5x^{5\coth(6x)}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\coth(6x)\ln(x))=$$
$$5x^{5\coth(6x)}\cdot\left(\ln(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\coth(6x))+\coth(6x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\ln(x))\right)=$$
$$5x^{5\coth(6x)}\cdot\left(\ln(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\coth(6x))+\coth(6x)\cdot\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$y(x)=x^{f(x)}\Leftrightarrow \ln(y(x))=f(x)\ln(x)$$

so that $$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\left(f(x)\ln(x)\right)'$$